# Git stash removes added changes

Tags: git, git-stash, git-index

During development, I routinely add working versions of files (but not commit them) to my git repo. I continue to work on those files, till they reach commitable stage, when I can commit them. So the repo looks like below

```
$ git status

# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   testfile1
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   testfile1
#   modified:   testfile2
```

When I do a `git stash`, and then do a `git stash pop`, I get

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   testfile1
#   modified:   testfile2
```

Questions

1. Why doesn't git stash them the way they were previously?
2. How do I stash my changes in one go, so that on doing a stash pop, I get the older state, and not the newer one?

Currently, I manually do

```
git stash --keep-index
git stash
git stash pop
git add <stashed_files>
git stash pop
```

Problem with this is

1. It takes 5 steps to stash & pop and I am looking for 2
2. I sometimes may not remember there were 2 back to back stashes, which slightly complicates the task.

Edit - I would prefer a command line solution, since I work in a similar fashion on test servers.

Comment: I use GitExtensions. The UI let's me stash-commit-push in two steps (commit and push is a single step after stash)

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Both outputs of `git status` are essentially the same. If you would do a commit right after the first `git status` you'd end up with a clean repository (`testfile1` would be committed in the state it was in last). Maybe I don't get your point...?

Comment: @MaxLeske the point is, the added version has code which works. It works, but can not be committed (say it is a highly unoptimal way of doing things). Now I work further on it, and the code is incorrect in the interim. In such a stage, if I stash and pop, I lose the working version as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use --index option.

```
git stash
git stash pop --index
```

Comment: This works! Can you tell me more about how git is stashing them?

Comment: you can see stash's commits revision number in .git/refs/stash , and git log [rev]. "stash" separates commits(index files, not staged and  untracked).

Answer (score 5):

I see this is already answered but let me add a bit more, and a warning: there's a buglet in `git stash`.

When you run `git stash` or `git stash save` (the default is `save` so these are the same thing) without using `-p`, the `stash` script—it lives in the `git-core` directory, whose location varies depending on the git installation, it may be in `/usr/libexec/git-core` or `/usr/local/libexec/git-core` for instance—creates a commit with two (or sometimes three) parent commits.  In order, these commits are:

- the current index
- with `-u` or `-a`, untracked and even ignored files (and it also uses `git clean` to ditch them from the working directory)
- the working directory, based on a delta between the current working directory and the `HEAD` commit (this is the source of the buglet; see below).

It then sets up `refs/stash` to point to the last of these commits, the working-directory commit.  This commit has as its parents:

- the HEAD commit, as `stash^` (first parent)
- the index commit, as `stash^2` (second parent)
- the untracked/ignored commit, as `stash^3` (third parent), if it exists.

This stash does in fact contain everything that was in place at the time of the stash, but the buglet shows up best when you use `git stash pop --index` or `git stash apply --index` to recover the "pre-stash state".  (I'm going to use `git stash apply` exclusively below, but `pop` is just `apply` followed by `drop`.)

Now, if you just run `git stash apply`, as you noted, it gives you a lot of `changes not staged for commit` files even though you had carefully staged some things before you ran `git stash save`.  This is because it's a lot easier to merge together these changes like this, regardless of work directory state, including if you've checked out a different branch or whatever, and including if you stage some files before running `git stash apply`.  (In fact, `git stash apply` uses git's merging code to bring in the work-directory changes.)

If you run `git stash apply --index`, though, the `stash` script first *tries* to add to the index exactly what you had in it at the time of the original `save`.  (If nothing is staged yet, this recovers your original state.)  Assuming it can do that, it then tries to set up the working directory similarly (again using the merge mechanisms).  If it can't set up the index properly, it does nothing to the index, and suggests you retry without `--index`.

Here's where the buglet comes in.  Suppose you start with a file, say `basefile`, with no changes.  You make a change and stage this:

```
$ cat basefile
base
$ git status --short
$ echo add to basefile >> basefile; git add basefile
```

but then you decide you want the working-directory copy to have no change from the `HEAD` revision:

```
$ ed basefile
21
2d
w
5
q
$ git status --short
MM basefile
```

The tricky bit here is that `basefile` is modified in the index, and then modified again in the work-dir, but the second change takes it back to what's in the `HEAD` commit.  When you run `git stash save`, the stash script accidentally records the *index* version as if it were the work-in-progress version.

If you now do a `git stash apply --index` and run `git status --short`:

```
$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 94824e1 initial
HEAD is now at 94824e1 initial
stash created
$ git stash apply --index
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   basefile
#
$ git status --short
M  basefile
```

Here git has restored the index version into the index, and then set the working-directory version to *the same thing that was in the index version*:

```
$ cat basefile
base
add to basefile
```

The fix for the stash script is a one-word change but so far no one seems to like it.  Perhaps the problem is that if you apply the stash *without* `--index`, this effectively combines the index change (the extra line, `add to basefile`) with nothing, so that the work-directory version has the extra line.  However, that's not consistent with the way it behaves when both index and working-directory versions are different:

```
$ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (61c83c866bc522c58df62320b77e647ffd28aa95)
$ echo base > basefile
$ git status --short
$ echo add to basefile >> basefile
$ git add basefile
$ ed basefile
21
2c
different change
w
22
q
$ git status --short
MM basefile
$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 94824e1 initial
HEAD is now at 94824e1 initial
$ git stash apply
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   basefile
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ cat basefile
base
different change
```

Here, by "mushing together" the index and work tree changes, but applying without `--index`, we recover *only* the work-tree changes.

(Fortunately since we're using `apply` instead of `pop` we can change our minds now:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 94824e1 initial
$ git stash apply -q --index
$ git status --short
MM basefile
```

and if we look at the index and work-dir versions, we can now see both versions of `basefile`.)

(The one-word fix to the stash script is to change `HEAD` to `$i_tree` in the line reading:

```
git diff --name-only -z HEAD -- >"$TMP-stagenames" &&
```

around line 118.  I posted this to the git mailing list and got ... crickets. :-) )